# replication VMs in availability set

Tags: availability

I have kind of a stupid question. I am starting to learn about MS Azure Cloud and planning on using an availability set in Azure. I understand that I need at least 2 VMs in my availability set.
However, if I create a new VM, does it automatically replicate all the data and applications from the first VM, or do I need to find a way for that? 
Also, may I also use the VMs from my availability set for the autoscale? As it would be a great way to get better performance based on use and limit cost for availability and performance. I understand I would also need a load balancer if I use it this way.

Sorry for the bad question, I just cannot find the answer.
Paul

Comment: `if I create a new VM, does it automatically replicate all the data and applications from the first VM` - No it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. So I should find a way to replicate everything? Or would it be better to actually use set up a recovery disaster?

Comment: We can't tell you what you need. Do you need high availability, or disaster recovery, or both?

Comment: I would actually like to have both HA and DR. However for now I am only doing lab tests to learn better the process and how it would work. So yes indeed for my labs I would like to be able to have only HA and another lab with HA and DR.
How would I be able to set up HA with 2 identical VMs?